# Delete specific image from loader

Tags: image, function, actionscript-3, bitmap, removechild

I have three images all from the same loader on screen. I need to delete a specific (targeted) bitmap once clicked. I have an onClick function below, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var nb_images:int = 3;

var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap;

var img_margin:int = stage.stageHeight/3.5;
var img_request:URLRequest;
var img_loader:Loader;

var images_container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(images_container);

function remove_all_images():void {
    for (var i:int = images_container.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        images_container.removeChildAt(i);
    }
}

function load_images():void {
    remove_all_images();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < nb_images; i++) {
        img_request = new URLRequest('../img/planet' + (int(nb_images * Math.random())) + '.png');
        img_loader = new Loader();
        img_loader.load(img_request);
        img_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_img_loaded);
    }
}

function on_img_loaded(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_img_loaded);
    bmp = e.currentTarget.content;
    bmp.x = 600, bmp.width = bmp.height = 80;
    bmp.y = images_container.numChildren * (bmp.height + img_margin);
    images_container.addChild(bmp);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        removeChild(e.target);
    }
}

load_images();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *specific (targeted) bitmap*? Are you trying to remove a bitmap when clicked? Right now, your code listens (three times) for a click on the stage, and then tries to remove `e.target` (which isn't even a `DisplayObject`) from the `DisplayList`. Please explain, in detail, what exactly you're trying to remove and when you're trying to remove it.

Comment: I have three images, each evenly spaced in a vertical line with the above code. I simply want to make a mouse event that will allow me to remove the image I click on. I realize that e.target is not a DisplayObject, that is what I need help with, thanks. Hope that brings clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first thing I did here was remove `var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap`. You're creating a reference you don't really need, so let's get rid of that altogether.

Now, in your `on_img_loaded` method, you're going to want to create a new `Bitmap` for each loaded image.

```
var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;
```

Then, you'll need to add the event listener directly to an `InteractiveObject` rather than the stage. Bitmaps are not `InteractiveObjects`, so we'll need to wrap it in something else before adding the listener.

```
var sprite: Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.addChild(bmp);
addChild(sprite);
sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

Finally, create a method to remove the clicked `Bitmap` from `images_container` (note here I removed the nested function - this prevents argument ambiguity and is generally good practice).

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    images_container.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
}
```

This is the relevant code in its entirety (untested).

```
//remove var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap from the beginning of the code
function on_img_loaded(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_img_loaded);
    var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;
    bmp.x = 600, bmp.width = bmp.height = 80;
    bmp.y = images_container.numChildren * (bmp.height + img_margin);
    var sprite: Sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.addChild(bmp);
    addChild(sprite);
    images_container.addChild(sprite);
    sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
}

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)
    images_container.removeChild(e.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and get the following error: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject. The error is highlighting images_container.removeChild(e.currentTarget);

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Change that line to `images_container.removeChild(e.currentTarget as Bitmap);`

Comment: Hmm, still not deleting the Bitmaps. I think that the Bitmaps are not detecting mouse input. No problems with compile though.

Comment: Ah, right. Bitmap is not an `InteractiveObject`, so it won't detect `MouseEvent`s. I've edited the original post to wrap the `Bitmap` in a `Sprite` container.

Comment: I tried your newly edited code, and I got the same error as before Error: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Fixed the problem and proposed an edit to your code, thank for your help!